# React - Check If Props Exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I searched around the internet for an answer to this question, and I didn't find one. Therefore I am posting my question here.

I have a parent component (App) and a child component (Child).
The App component has a state with some data in it, like so:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            currentOrganization: {
                name: 'name',
                email: 'email'
            }
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <Child data={this.state.currentOrganization} />
            )
        }
    }
}
```

In my Child component, I have a form:

```
class Child extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            formData: {
                name: '',
                email: '',
            }
        }
    }

        render() {
            return (
            <Form ... />
          )
        }
    }
```

According to the React docs, forms generally should have a state containing properties that correspond with each element of the form. The form that lies in my Child component must have the data of the currentOrganization (as seen in the App component) pre-populate into itself.

In order to accomplish this, I have to set the state of the Child to the props it receives from its parent.

What's the best way to check if my Child component received the props it needs in order to update its own state?

Comment: "What's the reason why the team at React didn't add a lifecycle function like componentDidReceiveProps()? " -> Does `componentWillReceiveProps()` not work for you? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: React have `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: What would it be for? I mean, you're the one that's passing the entire state instead of what the component actually needs--so you need to check the props in construction, didMount, willReceiveProps, etc. I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: Its just a guess but because there is a lifecycle event called `componentWillReceiveProps` and you need to set your state there since your props could possible cause a re-render and if you set your state after componentWillReceiveProps its gonna re-render again

Comment: @Matt Holland It won't work in this scenario. I need to check to make sure my Child component actually received the props. I don't need to know if the props will change, just simply if they exist to begin with.  If my understanding of that method is correct, that method "is invoked before a mounted component receives new props." Is that the case when it receives initial props upon mounting as well? Nonetheless, it seems the answer below will suffice.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can assign default props to component.

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      formData: {
        name: props.name,
        email: props.email,
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form ... />
    )
  }
}

Child.defaultProps = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
};
```

P.S.
 `props` is JS object so You can check property like this
 `"prop_name" in this.props // true|false`

Comment: +1 for using `props.xxx` in the constructor instead of `this.props` and for using empty string for input value instead of null.

Comment: That can also be written like: `const { name = '', email = '' } = props` and then `this.state.formData({ name, email })` in the *constructor*.

Comment: `this.state.formData()` ?

Comment: Sorry, was too busy while writing the latter part. Should be `this.state = { formData: { name, email } }`

Comment: @Rafael Hovsepyan cool, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: how if the props.xxx is a boolean type?

Comment: @Elaine this question about Form inputs, which accepts only string values.

Comment: your P.S. did the trick for me to help me distinguish between undefined and whether the prop was even passed. if ("prop_name" in props)... with "prop_name" as a string